# Scrapy logging twice

Tags: python, logging, scrapy, python-logging

I'm trying to add another piece of information to the scrapy spider log. The information i need to add will be accessible inside the **init** method:

```
def __init__(self, target: str, days_ago: int = 1):
    self.target = target  # -----here----
    self.now = datetime.now()
    self.days_ago = days_ago
```

I've tried to override the scrapy.Spider `logger` property as such:

```
@property
def logger(self):
    logger = logging.getLogger(self.name)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s [%(name)s] [%(target)s] [%(levelname)s] %(message)s')
    out_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    out_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(out_handler)
    extra = {'target': self.target, 'spider': self}
    return logging.LoggerAdapter(logger, extra)
```

The result is as expected:

```
2020-05-15 12:05:09,536 [spiderName] [spiderTarget] [INFO] Log test etc----------
```

But the log gets doubled with the original form of the log:

```
2020-05-15 12:05:09 [spiderName] INFO: Log test etc----------
```

I've checked and there is only one handler when printing `logging.getLogger(self.name).handlers`.

I just need to add that one extra information to the log and not have each log entry doubled.

PS: the logger call looks like this:

```
def start_requests(self):
    self.logger.info('Log test etc----------')
```

Comment: You are adding a Handler to a sub-logger. Now you have two active Handlers, the new one and the one of the root logger.

Comment: @KlausD Indeed, the root logger hand a handle. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

How i eventually solved it, might help someone somewhen:

```
def adjust_logging(self):
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s [%(name)s] [{target}] [%(levelname)s] %(message)s'.format(target=self.target))
    root_logger = logging.getLogger()
    handler = root_logger.handlers[1]
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
```

And call it inside scrapy spider **init**.